# receive xml file as a parameter to a .net web service

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

My company is currently looking into bringing a new piece of third party software in for online ordering. The software does not handle pricing so they are requesting the pricing information from a web service. Their software is passing an XML file as a parameter, and expecting an XML file as a response. I would think that returning an XML file would be pretty straight forward, but I cannot think of a way to receive an XML file as a parameter. Has anyone done this, or am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly obvious - an XML "file" can be represented by a `String`.

**Edit to Answer Comment**

The string **is** the XML file, so all you need to do is deserialize it into the classes created from the XSD:

```
Dim xmlString As String = GetStringFromVendor()
Dim xmlClass As New CoolXMLClass
Dim serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(CoolXMLClass))
xmlClass = serializer.Deserialize(New StringReader(xmlString))
```

Comment: We did this in a data import service and, yes, we just took it as a string and then parsed it using .NET's XML functionality. It is really just as easy as it sounds!

Comment: sweet, I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: I am finally getting around to this. Our software vendor provided us with an XSD file for the XML that they are sending us, and we have the classes created. How should I go about converting the string to the xml file and later the class defined in the xsd?